# Angular 4 - Every button clicks push the values to one array

Tags: angular, typescript

how am I able to do this? I am building a system which I can mark multiple checkbox then delete them simultaneously.

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="selChk(member.id)">
```

**component**

```
 selChk(val) {
  let id = [];

  let ids = id.push(val);
  console.log(ids);
 }
```

I like to output like this:

["0","1","2","3","4","5"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new array whenever you click the button. Declare it in your class instead of inside the function.

```
ids= [];

selChk(val) {
  this.ids.push(val);
  console.log(this.ids);
 }
```

Comment: hahahah I did this before but with a little difference, but thanks it works :)

Comment: Hi can I ask again, How can I remove the value from array when I uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: it is possible. you can use the .splice() function and use the index of the member to remove it from the list